# Python: Why am I getting a "ZeroDivisionError: division by zero" in function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

My goal is to count the total amount of tweets in a file that fall under certain time zones.
I have the following function (I have noted the trouble area near the end of the function with comments):

```
def readTweets(inFile, wordsName):    
words = []
lat = 0
long = 0
keyword = keywords(wordsName)
sents = keywordSentiment(wordsName)
value = 0
eastern = 0
central = 0
mountain = 0
pacific = 0
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0
d = 0
easternTweets = 0
centralTweets = 0
mountainTweets = 0
pacificTweets = 0

for line in inFile:
    entry = line.split()    

    for n in range(0, len(entry) - 1):
        entry[n] = entry[n].strip("[],!?#./-=+_@")
        if n > 4:   # n>4 because words begin on 5th index of list
            entry[n] = entry[n].lower()
            words.append(entry[n])

    lat = float(entry[0])
    long = float(entry[1])

    timezone = getTimeZone(lat, long)  
    if timezone == "eastern":
        easternTweets += 1
    if timezone == "central":
        centralTweets += 1
    if timezone == "mountain":
        mountainTweets += 1
    if timezone == "pacific":
        pacificTweets += 1

    for i in range(0, len(words)):
        for k in range(0, len(keyword)):
            if words[i] == keyword[k]:
                value = int(sents[k])
                if timezone == "eastern":
                    eastern += value
                    a += 1
                if timezone == "central":
                    central += value
                    b += 1
                if timezone == "mountain":
                    mountain += value
                    c += 1
                if timezone == "pacific":
                    pacific += value
                    d += 1

# the values of a,b,c,d are 0
easternTotal = eastern/a    # getting error 
centralTotal = central/b    # for 
mountainTotal = mountain/c  # these 
pacificTotal = pacific/d    # values

print("Total tweets per time zone:")
print("Eastern: %d" % easternTweets)
print("Central: %d" % centralTweets)
print("Mountain: %d" % mountainTweets)
print("Pacific: %d" % pacificTweets)
```

I am getting a `ZeroDivisionError: division by zero` error for `easternTotal` and the other total values that use `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` for division.

If I print the values of `a`, `b`, `c`, or `d` it shows `0`. My question is why are their values 0? Does the value of `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` not change in the `if` statements?

Comment: If `inFile` is empty, or a line doesn't contain `lat` and `long` which when passed to  `getTimeZone` returns '`eastern'` then `a` will be `0`. Read up on how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Fix your indentation please and show how you’re calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

So the only way this can happen is because the code that increments a, b, c and d is never reached.

That can have a few reasons:

- `inFile` is empty so the whole for loop never enters its body
- `len(words)` is 0, so that for loop never enters its body
- `len(keywords)` is 0, so that for loop never enters its body
- The value of `timezone` is something other than those values you test for

`words` is initially `[]`, so its length can stay 0 if that loop that appends things to it never runs.

From here, it's impossible for us to see which of these is happening, but it should be very easy for you with some print statements or such.

Answer (score 0):

you divide `eastern` by `0`. You can avoid it by doing

```
easternTotal = eastern/a if a > 0 else eastern
```

Answer (score 0):

because you set a,b,c,d=0;
when readTweets(inFile, wordsName) did not get any data, "eastern/a" may cause "eastern/0 " .

So, make sure your readTweets() did get data first.